# How get array and copy to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello everyone My project has a model.
It returns all values in the array.

```
    let DATA = {
    result: [
        { id: 1, name: 'test', data: '2001-01-01', status: STATUS_OPEN },
        { id: 2, name: 'test', data: '2001-01-01', status: STATUS_IN_PROCESS },
    ]
}
export function getAllA () {
    return (new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(DATA.result)
    }))
}
```

I need to copy the array returned by this method to the "arr" array.I do this:

```
    let arr = []
    getAllA().then((item)=>{
    arr = item.slice()})
```

It doesn't copy.Please tell me what the problem is?How can I fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by "It doesn't copy"? Where are you declaring `arr` and where are you trying to use it? What makes you think that it doesn't copy?

Comment: `@Nick Parsons` . I edited my response. I'm sorry that I didn't show initialization the array.
Why do I think it doesn't copy?Because the array remains empty.And if I try to log it.In the log I will see only `[]`

Comment: Where do you try and log it? Outside of the `.then()` function? The code outside your `.then()` function will run _before_ the code inside your `.then()` function

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, for the example I replaced export default with a function.

(you should care, this example use a `shallow copy`, since the array contains objects, there'll still remain references between original and the copy objects)

```js
const data = {
  result: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'test',
      data: '2001-01-01',
      status: 'STATUS_OPEN'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test',
      data: '2001-01-01',
      status: 'STATUS_IN_PROCESS'
    },
  ]
}

function getAllA() {
  return Promise.resolve(data.result);
}

(async () => {
  const arr = await getAllA()
    .then((item) => /* shallow copy */ [...item]);
    
  // use the array here
  console.log(arr);
})();
```

Comment: The solution is good, thank you.
But the problem is that the array exists only in the function.
That is, if I suddenly need to contact him in another part of the code, he will not see it

Comment: I updated my example, you can do something like this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy an object, then it is a bit more complicated than that. Please not that JSON.parse...JSON.stringify approach WILL not work in some cases ( for example functions  or object instances )

you should probably check out lodash if you can.. it has a very nifty tool cloning function:

https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep

If you do not care about shallow clones then the fastest and best approach would be using Array.from(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Read up on javascript shallow copying:
https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c?gi=42d71cd90591

Comment: Thank you for your answer and a lot of useful information.
at this stage, I don't care if I use deep copying or shallow copying.The question is that Array.from() doesn't work either